# What happens if we connect GND and +5v?

Tags: power, arduino-nano

What will happen if I by mistakenly connect GND and +5v of an Arduino Nano? Is there any protection for it? Or will it get short and fry out something?

Comment: You'll probably fry the voltage regulator, I don't believe it's protected.

Comment: How to check whether its fried

Comment: The Magic Smoke™ will escape.

Comment: Actually, I have really burned my Arduino Nano and What should I do I don't know

Comment: And my CH340G was smelling

Comment: Throw it away and get a real one.

Comment: if you're handy with SMD work, you can swap out a blown regulator or diode on an MCU

Comment: One more thing I programmed it to behave as a voltage regulator and I was saying it send data to my PC Now when I plug it with a battery first the tx and led get really high for a sec and then tx stays on for sometime then it stops and then the led starts blinking very fast and after a few secs it gets dim

Comment: It maybe the Ch340g or the diode

Comment: I think I burned my CH340G because yesterday when I plugged it into my computer there was Hardware named Ch340g in the coms but after issue it isn't there and even it was even smelling quite a bit !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how you are powering your board different things will happen.

1. If you are powering through USB from a PC the PC should, according to the USB standard, detect an over-current situation and disconnect the power from the port. However some don't, in which case see point 2.
2. If you are powering through USB from a USB power supply (phone charger, etc) the charger's output voltage will drop to near zero and the current will hit maximum for the supply. This may or may not damage the supply, but either way it's not a nice thing to do.
3. If you are powering from a small external battery (say a 9V PP3 battery) things will start to get hot. The voltage regulator will most likely overheat, the battery may overheat, but not much damage should occur - a small PP3 battery can't provide much current.
4. If you are powering from a large external battery (e.g., Li-Ion cells) or an external power supply, things will get more nasty. The on-board regulator will overheat. If it isn't thermally protected (genuine Arduinos should be, but cheap Chinese clones may not be) then it will fail and you will find smoke coming out of the regulator. At this point the regulator is dead. If the board contains a polarity protection diode that may fail in the same way (I have seen these blow clean off the board before). Physical damage (blackening and blistering) may occur to the PCB as well.

So all in all shorting +5V to GND is never a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this image](http://cdn-tienda.bricogeek.com/847-thickbox_default/arduino-pro-mini-328-5v-16mhz.jpg) and [this datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic5205.pdf), that nano's voltage regulator is internally limited.

That means it will heat up and shut down if over-loaded. Of course, your nano could use a less-effective regulator and simply smoke away. It's also possible that the 5205 would not clamp in time to prevent damage on an instant dead-short. Generally, i've found the arduino boards to be fairly resilient, compared to other MCUs, so you can *probably* get away with it at least a time or two.

Dead shorting is never a good idea even if you can get away with it because there can be incremental (as opposed to catastrophic) damage. You might cause instability in the regulator, and you might limit it's ability to limit volts. Those problems might not be revealed instantly, but instead at the worst (unexpected) time.

EDIT:
based on your edit, it sounds like your "FTDI" is fried, but not *necessarily* your MCU.

Comment: I think I burned my CH340G because yesterday when I plugged it into my computer there was Hardware named Ch340g in the coms but after issue it isn't there and even it was even smelling quite a bit !